# Creating Dashboard Templates in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, template, dashboard

I have a dashboard that took some time to build and I would like to use it as a template for other projects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a duplicate of your dashboard, click the arrow next to Save, click Save As..., and specify a title, tags, a summary, and a folder for the duplicate. With this duplicate you could rename it to be called template and put in a group for templates for findability in the future.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately there is no easy way to change the map which the dashboard is based on.  Removing the map also removes the elements that are based on the map.  If you remove the map and add a different one you have to add and reconfigure all the elements which is a time suck. So this method doesn't really work. You should just be able to change the source of the map without deleting it and all the elements, just like changing the source of data in desktop.

Comment: Agreed, it's not as straightforward as changing data sources in desktop. You could also use web appbuilder with the dashboard template and export a template from that: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/manage-apps/export-as-template.htm